# PHP Mailscript - adding a simple condition to block spam bots

Tags: php, jquery, html

My knowledge on PHP is just too limited to fully understand my possibilities.

### The current situation

I've been adapting the Mailscript from Ondrej Svestka of Bootstrap Temple. He posted this script over 2 years ago, and I've been using it with huge success. But not in AJAX mode (since Firefox updates always messes up the functionality), but actually "send mail -> forward to next page".

In the early days of using this script, my server was instantly hammered with spam bots. So I had to introduce a .htaccess rule to prevent direct access of the .php mailscript, this already reduced a lot of unnecessary spam. However, as of late, I'm getting more and more mails in foreign languages, and spam about stuff that is completely unrelated.

So I dug into the documentation of that script (the comment section of Svestka's blog post) and found a comment to "add a hidden form block, and then check if it remains empty - because bots will fill that out". So I implemented that, but had it as CSS style:hidden - so it didn't trigger. Last night, I made the block visible while adding the information "please leave the field blank", and the spam reduced again. However, it is still happening.

I am fully aware that you can't fight spam bots - but let's not make it overly easy for them either. I could implement a Captcha system, but I saw on another page I'm administrating, how easily that could be broken as well (since bots can now easily go around such engines). Not only that, my code would be needed to be massively overhauled. And honestly - I rather keep things simple.

**WHAT IS THE ACTUAL CODE?**

I'm using a PHP file that contains the form, this file accesses the jQuery validate.js, a .js file that triggers the validate code (previously needed for AJAX, but I removed that - since it caused issues) and finally the mail script itself in PHP form

**Here is the form itself**

```
                    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="../assets/mailscript.php" role="form">

                    <div class="controls">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_name">Firstname <span class="warning-star">*</span></label>
                                    <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_lastname">Lastname <span class="warning-star">*</span></label>
                                    <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_email">Email <span class="warning-star">*</span></label>
                                    <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_url">URL (Demo Track, homepage, social media, etc)</label>
                                    <input id="form_url" type="text" name="url" class="form-control" placeholder="Please provide an URL - http://">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="check">If you're a human being, please leave the next field blank</label>
                                    <input id="check" type="text" name="check" class="form-control" style="width:50px;"> <!-- no bots! -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_purpose">What is the contact reason</label>
                                    <select id="form_purpose" name="purpose" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="General Questions">I have general questions</option>
                                        <option value="Client Inquiry">I'd like to book your services</option>
                                        <option value="Opt Out">Please update my personal info (opt out)</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_message">Message <span class="warning-star">*</span></label>
                                    <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your message" rows="5" required="required" data-error="Please leave us a message."></textarea>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <p class="text-muted text-right"><span class="warning-star">*</span> required</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div> <!-- .controls -->

                    <div class="messages"></div>

                </form>
```

**Here is the mailscript PHP**

```
<?php

// configure
$from = 'mail@server.com'; 
$sendTo = 'mail@server.com';
$subject = 'Homepage Name - new message from contact form';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'email' => 'Email', 'url' => 'URL', 'purpose' => 'Purpose', 'message' => 'Message', 'check' => 'checking for spam'); // array variable name => Text to appear in email
$okMessage = 'Thank you, submission successful. We will get back to you ASAP';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// let's do the sending

try
{
    $emailText = "You have one new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }


    $headers = array

    ( 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
    'From: ' . $from,
    'Reply-To: ' . $from, 
    'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );

    if (empty($_POST['check'])) {                                   // checks if the hidden "check" form is empty or not)
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));   // the code to send the mail
    }

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if ($responseArray['type'] == 'success') {
    // success redirect

    header('Location: ../pages/contact-success.php');
}
else {
    //error redirect
    header('Location: ../pages/contact-fail.php');
}
?>
```

That script is working like it should. Enter your mandatory information, hit send, get forwarded to either an error message or confirmation page. Short time after, I do get a mail.

It also works if the "spam check" field is left blank. If somebody enters anything, you still get the confirmation page, but I do not get a mail (could be better handled though, but let's not train the bot AI's).

Now the problem is, that I still(!) get spam mails, even if the field is left blank. So I was like "a simple question could work". And in fact, apparently there is a codes snippet to change. But I'm unsure if this is correct, or could be handled in a better way.

Instead of the following:

```
if (empty($_POST['check'])) {                                   // checks if the hidden "check" form is empty or not)
mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));   // the code to send the mail
}
```

I could ask for users of this script to insert a simple word or do a quick math equation. Then the code (according to the original code writer) would look like this:

```
if ($_POST['check'] !== 22) throw new \Exception();
mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));   // the code to send the mail
```

So if there would be the value 22 to insert (from math or whatever), then the `mail($sendTo...` would be triggered? Is that correct? Can't I change the comparison operator in the condition (if/then/else) to == instead? Or am I over-complicating things?

What if I want to read out a string, and one user writes it in lowercase, another one with upper and lowercase, and yet another with complete uppercase? Do I need to go the && route?

**WHAT SHALL THE SCRIPT ULTIMATELY DO?**

In a nutshell - people shall fill out the form and do the quick "human check" (either a math question or just "please insert the following word here"), then hit send. Keeping it as simple and as compatible to as many devices as possible.

The question though... is the "throw new \Exception();" a good/working solution, or will the mail be sent regardless?

Comment: Where's the problem using Google ReCaptcha? There's even an extensive documentation on how to use it with PHP.

Comment: I agree with Spingolini. All you are doing is inventing your own captcha, which any (except the least sophisticated of bots) will be able to get through, and there is no need when the google one is already production-ready, and incredibly simple to implement (You do not need to overhaul your code).

Comment: I want to keep it simple, hence no "recaptcha". Because let's be honest for a moment - that#s also already broken/evaded by bots (in fact, I've seen this at another place I'm running with a phpBB)

I can do a lot with htaccess and checking for certian words once the mail arrived. And the spam already went down so far as well. I just want to add another small "human layer". That's all

And I want to know if the code that I got is acceptable